# how to execute original method after callback finished?

Tags: java, android, api, asynchronous, synchronous

there are some problem when I develop my code.
for ex)

a.java

```
public OnResultCallbackListener(){

part C

}


protected void onCreate(){

(skipped)
      button.setOnClickListener(){
            method a(arg0, arg1, arg2, ...., OnResultCallbackListener);
            --------------------------------
            part B
            --------------------------------
      }
}
```

I want to execute in this order.
when I click button, method a executed. And method A will call callback(OnResultCallbackListener)
and when OnResultCallbackListener finished(part C), code below method a executed(part B)

so, the order is
method A - OnResultCallbackListener (part C) - part B.
but my code executes part B first. OnResultCallbackListener needs server connection, so I cannot modify it.

in this situation, How can I execute my code in the way that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper the callback listener with a compound listener.

```java
public OnResultCallbackListener(){
    // part C
}
public CompoundCallbackListener(){
    OnResultCallbackListener();
    // part B
}

protected void onCreate() {
    // (skipped)
    button.setOnClickListener(){
        method a(arg0, arg1, arg2, ...., CompoundCallbackListener);
    }
}
```